# ASP MVC Validation dropdownbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

I'm using model validation in MVC to validate my forms.

I do it like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CarModel))]
public partial class Car {...}


public class CarModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select the brand please")]
    [Display(Name = "Brand* :")]
    public object brand_id { get; set; }

    ...
 }
```

In my View I have this code for the dropdownbox:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.brand_id, new SelectList(ViewBag.brands, "id", "name"), new {@class = "selectBoxes" })
```

And the Viewbag.brands is filled like this:

```
List<Brand> brands = Brand.GetAllBrands();
ViewBag.brands = brands;
```

(Brands has the fields "id" (int) "name" (string)), the Car class/table uses "brand_id" as reference.

When I want to sent an empty form, normally Formvalidation should work, but I get an error on the @Html.DropDownListFor:

```
ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
Value cannot be null.
```

What is the problem? The creation of the dropdownbox? Or isn't formvalidation working correct?
The brand-names are loaded correct in the dropdownbox and there is NO "0" value like (-- Select --), the first brand is displayed in the dropdownbox... But when I send an empty form it gets stuck on the dropdownlist...

EDIT: Maybe the problem is that Car uses "brand_id" and Brand uses "id"? If yes, how to solve this without changing this field-names?

EDIT2: Brand is just a partial class of Brands (Linq), with function:

```
public static List<Brand> GetAllBrands()
{
    db = new CarsDataClassesDataContext();
    return db.Brands.OrderBy(b => b.name).ToList<Brand>();
 }
```

Comment: Please post the definition of the `Brand` class.

Comment: When the dropdown was being created, ViewBag.brands is null. Are you sure your initialization code (ViewBag.brands = brands) was executed? Use a breakpoint to be sure. Can you post your controller?

Comment: ViewBag.brands is filled because the dropdownbox is shown correct with the brandnames in it, but when I send the form, I get the error... Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: When you said, "send the form" did you mean submit the form? In which case, you must have a GET method that originally obtained the form and a POST method that is for submitting the form. Can you show your action methods?

Comment: I submit the form to a HttpPost : http://s24.postimg.org/c5kuig6px/Screen_Shot_2014_01_16_at_09_59_49.png

Comment: ViewBag.brands was filled during GET but not during POST. It's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from your POST method, if the ModelState is invalid it will return to the same view, in which case you will have to reinitialized ViewBag.brands all over again.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     // perform your logic here
}

// if you reached this code, that means the model validation failed
// so you will have to reinitialize the ViewBag

ViewBag.brands = Brand.GetAllBrands();
return View(car);
```